# static const void *method() in C

Tags: objective-c, c, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have seen this on a program that I am tinkering:

```
static const void *method()
{
 // other code
 return anotherMethod(param1,param2);
}
```

For what I understand, this will return a pointer to a function. Now based on [this](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#function_pointers), I am trying to figure it what the `static const void` are applied to:

```
int f(void);
int *fip(); //Function returning int pointer
int (*pfi)(); //Pointer to function returning int
```

So what are the **real** advantages of adding the `static const` (assuming this is applied to the return valued of the appointed function). Also, will the return pointer to a function be called? Or it's just a pointer to it? Because from the code I have the following:

```
void start()
{
  method();
}
```

I am assuming it will be called, otherwise it would have been assigned to a pointer.

Comment: Just a sidenote: I believe you are confusing C and C++. In C++, `start()` means `start(void)` and the former is encouraged style. But in C, `start()` means "function accepting various junk parameters in hope for subtle bugs". In C you should always write `start(void)`. A function with no parameters is flagged as an obsolete feature in the C standard and might be removed from the language in the future (see C11 6.11.6).

Comment: I am actually using on a objective-c context and the name of the method was completely arbitrary. But thanks for the side note..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the function will return a `const void*` and the `static` restricts the visibility of the function to file scope.

Comment: Ok, so if I don't care about the returning, is there a good reason to actually return a `const void*`? Is it a good practice?

Comment: It informs the caller that returned value is not to be modified, so yes it is useful. However, the `const`ness can be casted away but at least the intention is clear and the caller has to intentionally cast it away, rather than accidentally modify it.

Answer (score 3):

`static` means that the function is private to the compilation unit (the source file) and not visible outside of it.

`const void *` means that the return value is a pointer to constant memory, i.e. memory that should not be written to.

Answer (score 1):

static keyword before a function does not mean it will return a static variable. it just means that the function is "static". that means this function is not accessible from a "external" object like object file compiled from another source file.

The example you have given, will return

```
const void*
```

And will refused to link to any external references to this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
static const void *method()
```

It returns a "const void*". This could be a function pointer cast into a void*, but in general this shouldn't be the case.

```
void start()
{
  method();
}
```

In here, the caller simply isn't interested in the result. Nothing magic happening at all.